# How can i fix this for firebase firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called info, inside info there are docs that contain fields info1-info99, there are also other fields inside these docs i want to only extract info1-info99 so I can place them into an array

How can I pull only the info1-info99 from the doc? I will only need one doc :

`firestore().collection('info').get() .where(...)` I have no clue what comes next

Comment: I will need to know how to filter or map the array so it only returns the fields with info in the name

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot fetch a single (multiple selected fields) from Firestore. The process involves fetching the whole document and then parsing it yourself. You can try the following code to parse those fields:

```
const queryRef = await firebase.firestore().collection("info").where(...)
queryRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  const parsedDocs = []
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const docObj = {}
    for (let i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
      docObj[i] = doc.data()[`info${i}`]
    }
    parsedDocs.push({ id: doc.id, ...docObj })
  })
})
```